# Upgrading Linux on a docker-compose --build install

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I am trying to run an openboxes docker installation but it won't install because of it being based on Jasper and it having issues being able to install software because of the distribution not being available. It just fails during the apt-get operations. I have tried all the fixes but just getting on a newer version of the operation system probably would work.  How can I do this.  How can I have it upgrade the Linux from Jasper to the latest or 19.xx during the docker-compose --build part of the installation?

Any help would be appreciated.

The errors I am getting but cannot resolve:

> Step 4/15 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y     unzip     zip
> curl              wget     git     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
> ---> Running in 52238d44699d Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease
>
> Err http://deb.debian.org jessie InRelease
>
> Err http://deb.debian.org jessie Release.gpg   Temporary failure
> resolving 'deb.debian.org' Err http://security.debian.org
> jessie/updates Release.gpg   Temporary failure resolving
> 'security.debian.org' Reading package lists... W: Failed to fetch
> http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/InRelease
>
> W: Failed to fetch
> http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/jessie/updat
> es/InRelease
>
> W: Failed to fetch
> http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/jessie/updat
> es/Release.gpg  Temporary failure resolving 'security.debian.org'
>
> W: Failed to fetch
> http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/Release.gpg  Tempor
> ary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
>
> W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
> ones used          instead. Reading package lists... Building
> dependency tree... Reading state information... Package zip is not
> available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that
> the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from
> another source
>
> E: Package 'zip' has no installation candidate ERROR: Service 'grails'
> failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update          &&
> apt-get install -y     unzip     zip     curl     wget     git     &&
> rm -rf          /var/lib/apt/lists/*' returned a non-zero code: 100

Comment: Maybe you can post a sample of docker-compose.yml/Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could delete my original post. I couldn't find a way to do it but did find another docker implementation and was able to use that instead. Thank you for your interest in helping.

Comment: it is possible to delete your own post.   Read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question